# How to generate HTTP header digest authentication value from input params?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, ember.js, frontend

I have html form with such variables:

- username
- realm
- password
- nonce
- algorithm
- qop
- nonceCount
- clientNonce
- opaque

I want to generate appropriate HTTP header from that values using javascript on the frontend. Actually, I need some javascript library with function, which accepts that params and returns header value. But if there are no such libraries, you can advise some simple way how can I generate it.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you'll be writing a custom setup to match your needs, I wouldn't expect to find a library that does that for you. That said, if you look at `ember-simple-auth`, it has examples that demonstrate doing things in a similar manner to what you need.